# json.loads to list not dict

Tags: python, json

I am running into an issue that Google had not been able to address for me.

I understand that `json.loads(var.text)` will return a `dict`, and in some cases it will for me.

Say the data looks like this:

```
{
    "PROJECT_ID": 3351040882,
    "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
    "servermain.PROJECT_TITLE": "",

}
```

This data will load as a `dict`!

Here is a sample of the data that is loading as a list.

```
[  
    {
        "PROJECT_ID": 3351040882,
        "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "AdvancedTags",
        "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
        "servermain.ALIAS_MAPPED_TO": "_AdvancedTags",
        "servermain.ALIAS_SCAN_RATE_MILLISECONDS": 0
    },
    {
        "PROJECT_ID": 3351040882,
        "common.ALLTYPES_NAME": "Channel1__CommunicationSerialization",
        "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION": "",
        "servermain.ALIAS_MAPPED_TO": "Channel1._CommunicationSerialization",
        "servermain.ALIAS_SCAN_RATE_MILLISECONDS": 0
    },
]
```

From my research I understand the second output is a `list` of `dict`s. Is there some simple function to load a `list` into a `dict`?

Comment: 1st item of list isn't equals to 2nd, so how do you see your `dict`? Please post reqiured output for your example.

Comment: No, there's no built-in that will do it—which is likely why you can find anything. As @sKwa says, please [edit] your question and show what the dictionary should contain if one was created from the second set of sample data (the `list` of `dict`s)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just have one dictionary in the list. Then simply access it by index:

```
json.loads(var.text)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I trimmed up the output quite a bit. As to not flood the post.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix, I'm sure there is a better way, but here is what I did. First I built a list of lists and dicts. Then I built a dict and loaded dict this way.

```
# List of lists and dicts
serverintlist = [project_info, aliases_info, channels_info]
serverintdict = {}
serverintdict['project'] = serverintlist[0]
serverintdict['alias'] = serverintlist[1]
serverintdict['channel'] = serverintlist[2]
print(type(project_info))  # <class 'dict'>
print(type(aliases_info))  # <class 'list'>
print(type(channels_info)) # <class 'list'>
print(type(serverintdict)) # <class 'dict'>
```